# Android Retrofit "Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference"

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, retrofit

Hi first of all i searched some similar questions like mine but unfortunately i couldn't find the similarity of my code to them so please here me out

I have a Main Activity Class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public ProgressDialog loading;
public String[] itemer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RetrofitHandler handler = new RetrofitHandler();
    handler.getContacts(MainActivity.this);
}

public void getter(String[] response, int size) {
    String[] itemer;
    itemer = new String[size];
    if (response != null) {
        itemer = response;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, itemer[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And a Handler for my result

```
public class RetrofitHandler {
public String[] item;
public static final String ROOT_URL = "http://api.androidhive.info";
public List<Contacts> contacts;

// final MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
public void getContacts(final Context context) {
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Fetching Data", "Please wait...", false, false);

    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(ROOT_URL).build();
    ContactsAPI api = adapter.create(ContactsAPI.class);

    api.getContacts(new Callback<Contacts>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Contacts contacts, Response response) {
            loading.dismiss();
            MainActivity update = new MainActivity();
            List<Contact> contactList = contacts.getContacts();

            item = new String[contactList.size()];
            int size = contactList.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < contactList.size(); i++) {
                item[i] = contactList.get(i).getName();
            }
            update.getter(item, size);
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


}
```

But I get an error on my response in the main activity here is my log

```
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                                                                         at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:87)
                                                                         at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:81)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getResources(AppCompatActivity.java:542)
                                                                         at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:102)
                                                                         at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:259)
                                                                         at com.exist.kelvs.retrofit2.MainActivity.getter(MainActivity.java:55)
                                                                         at com.exist.kelvs.retrofit2.RetrofitHandler$1.success(RetrofitHandler.java:41)
                                                                         at com.exist.kelvs.retrofit2.RetrofitHandler$1.success(RetrofitHandler.java:28)
                                                                         at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(CallbackRunnable.java:45)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I maked sure that the handler item where not null tested it with toast but when i pass it to getter it gives me the error where did i do wrong? :(

Comment: what is line no.55 in your MainActivity??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> MainActivity update = new MainActivity();
> ```

Never instantiate activities with `new`. They are not initialized to be useful.

Instead, you can pass your activity as a reference where needed. Change

```
public void getContacts(final Context context)
```

to e.g.

```
public void getContacts(final MainActivity mainActivity)
```

and use `mainActivity` where you need an activity `Context` (such as with `Dialog`s) and when you need to invoke a method on `MainActivity`.

Note that generally passing activity references to async operations can be prone to significant memory leaks, and you need to take activity lifecycle into account - the activity might not be active when the async operation finishes.

Comment: Thank you very much that works very well. but one last thing what if I need to call my handler with another class what approach should i use?

Comment: @laalto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219078/error-with-progress-dialog can you please help me out.. I am stuck on this problem only on Marshmallow

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the toast in your main activity or replace Mainactivity.this to getApplicationContext() .

from :
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, itemer[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

to :

```
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), itemer[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Tryed your solution when i delete the toast it runs good but when i tried your getApplicationContext() the error is still the same :(

Comment: i think that your array itemer is empty  . you are declaring itemer 2 times in the class and in the getter function check it maybe that cause the emty value of your array .