# Android progrees dialog error how to solve this?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, progressdialog

I got an error on marshmallow device like below: but below marshmallow OS progress dialog working fine.
Error As follow:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
  at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.setupView(AlertController.java:489)
 at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:234)
 at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:423)
at android.app.ProgressDialog.onCreate(ProgressDialog.java:198)
at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:394)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:295)
```

My Code of progress dialog is as below:

```
 private void setUIToWait(boolean wait) {

        if (wait) {
            progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            progressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
            progressDialog.show();
            progressDialog.setContentView(new ProgressBar(LoginActivity.this));

        } else {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
```

and I got error in above code and my asynk task where I Actually call

```
 protected void onPreExecute() {

            setUIToWait(true);
        }
```

I don't know What is the problem.. It works file till fri on marshmallow but now every time it gives me an error when my app runs and service call with progress dialog in android device.. please suggest me any solution in my code only. Because I already tried all links and their solutions...

EDIT:

if I write below code

```
 private void setUIToWait(boolean wait) {

                if (wait) {
if(progressDialog==null){
                    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    progressDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
                    progressDialog.show();
                    progressDialog.setContentView(new ProgressBar(LoginActivity.this));
        }
                } else {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

            }
```

then It will not showing any error and execute successfully but ProgressDialog is not shown now..

Comment: Guys don't give negative vote.. I really don't understand why people used to do this... I want help not vote....

Comment: put log,e  inside if and else and check before creating progress dialog it is dismissing or not

Comment: you are getting here _progressDialog.setContentView(new ProgressBar(LoginActivity.this));_ /

Comment: post your whole code..I can't find findviewbyId in this code.

Comment: remove this line and run again `progressDialog.setContentView(new ProgressBar(LoginActivity.this));`

Comment: @KrishnaJ there is no any findviewbyid for progressDialog.. I already post progressDialog code. and this is working code below marshmallow.. but not on Marshmallow my app gets crashed..

Comment: @Benjamin Ok Thanks I will Try now..

Comment: negative is there because this is a question asked hundreds time so won't help community to add another one , so don't take it personally

Comment: @Benjamin Same Error after removing this line..

Comment: Did u check that when your condition match this _progressDialog.dismiss();_ ? It will be a null

Comment: I think you got error on other place and you are finding other.

Comment: @Asmi What do you exactly want to do ? Want to show PBD and dismiss it in on post execute?

Comment: @Piyush I did same but I got this error.. And if I check ProgressDialog==null then code work but progress Dialog not shown..

Comment: @Asmi Just simple. Make PBD variable global. Initialize it as u did. But before initialize just check that if it is not null and not showing then dismiss it in _onPreExecute()_ method and in _onPostExecute()_ method dismiss it

Comment: @Asmi Check my working code http://hastebin.com/lohecarepo.avrasm

Comment: @Piyush Hey Piyush Thank you so much.. I will Try..

Comment: @Asmi is it solved?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122187/discussion-between-asmi-and-piyush).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering Custom Progress Dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185166/centering-custom-progress-dialog)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a check for null

```
else {
           if( progressDialog != null) 
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code for hiding progress dialog:

```
else {
if (dialog != null) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            Context context = ((ContextWrapper)dialog.getContext()).getBaseContext();
            if (context instanceof Activity) {
                if (!((Activity) context).isFinishing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
            } else
                dialog.dismiss();
        }
        dialog = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added your code but still error comes.. Please check my edited code now.. It works file but not showing progressdialog now..